# Apache and two networks - only on one accepts connections

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, raspbian

Got Raspberry Pi 3 with two networks configured (one via ethernet, one via wifi):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:82:ca:0c
          inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::57ac:b6e:33c1:8bbb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:797 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:797 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:219915 (214.7 KiB)  TX bytes:117516 (114.7 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d7:9f:59
          inet addr:192.168.2.200  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6463:5ba:3b28:6d39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1532 errors:0 dropped:1215 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:364160 (355.6 KiB)  TX bytes:29417 (28.7 KiB)
```

---

```
sigma@sigma:~ $ ip route show table main
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 202
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0  metric 303
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.200  metric 202
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.200  metric 303
```

---

Port 80 is being forwarded, so the device would be available from networks public ips.

But the problem is that Apache seems to respond only when connection comes from first network... from second network I am getting an error (in browser), that site is unavailable.

At first I thought it may be some port forwarding problem, but using `iftop` I can see that from both networks browser is trying to connect (I can see incomming connection when connecting through both networks).

What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work on both networks at once?

PS. As you can see, on wlan0 there are alot of dropped packets (`dropped:1215`).

Comment: I don't think so, It has to be some routing problem, as SSH doesn't work neither. Server version: `Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian)` ... `Listen 80` ... `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: @JakeGould: Name-based virtual hosts generally tend to mean the exact opposite of specific-IP binding, don't they

Comment: @JakeGould: Apache has never to my knowledge arbitrarily chosen the "first" IP address – if you do not _manually_ specify an address, it binds to the 0.0.0.0 "wildcard". That's also what `<VirtualHost *:80>` means.

Comment: that is surely not a case, because I can connect through both interfaces via local network

Answer (score 1):

By default, Linux chooses routes for each packet purely based on *destination*. If both interfaces provide default routes, the one with lowest metric will always be selected – even if it's technically for the wrong network, and even if the initial packet arrived through a different interface.

Currently you can work around this by creating *additional* routing tables:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table 100
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0 table 200

ip rule add from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup 100
ip rule add from 192.168.2.0/24 lookup 200
```

(This is probably not perfect, *and* has to be done manually in case you're using DHCP. Something using fwmark might work better.)

Test using:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8
ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.200
ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.2.200
```

Comment: After copy-paste to console I get disconnected from SSH and I am unable to connect again until reboot... eth0 has static ip set (via dhcp.conf), wlan0 gets static ip from router dhcp... I was connected through eth0.

Comment: But it seems that it works... ruins shh local connection tho' ... I am not able to connect to ssh via local address, but Apache seems to work on both public addresses... could You please help me to fix that? This is bad because I got 2 other Raspberries in network and they can't communicate with each other anymore.

Comment: Please help? ...